# It's possible to restore data deleted one month ago?

Tags: ipad, restore, ios, data

I ask if it's possible to resore some pictures taked last month an deleted from my iPad.
More precisely, when I taked the pictures I wasn't connected to the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've deleted the pictures within the last 30 days, they are still available in the "Deleted pictures" album/folder within the Photos app on your iPad. If the deletion occured more than 30 days, they are unfortunately gone.

While it might be possible to recover the data even after the 30 days, the sandboxed architecture of iOS, the hardware encryption used and the ongoing file system writes by other apps make this a rather theoretical approach.

Comment: Patrix, despite your solution to the problem, are you sure that _if the deletion occured more than 30 days, they are unfortunately gone._ I think that if the data are not been overwrite yet a restore program can help you to restore deleted files. What do you think about that?

Comment: 'not overwritten' on a hardware-encrypted flash device doesn't really mean much. One the pointers have been removed from the directory structure, there's not a lot of hope of getting anything back.

Comment: @Tetsujin I just read something related to this. I wasn't aware of the different cancellation process of a flash memory. It's nice to know that!

Comment: It does make me wonder about those utilities that reckon to be able to pull data from a device in DFU mode... I mean, if it was that simple, why would the FBI be getting into such a flap over Apple unlocking a phone for them?